# How to change ion-label color while checking ion-radio on Ionic 6?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a following chunk of Ionic code,

```html
<ion-radio-group>
  <ion-item class="ship-method">
    <ion-label>Flat Rate £0.00</ion-label>
    <ion-radio slot="end" value="flat-rate"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="ship-method">
    <ion-label>Free Shipping</ion-label>
    <ion-radio slot="end" value="free-shipping"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>
```

and following part of SCSS code,

```css
.ship-method {
    margin: 25px;

    ion-label { font-size: 16px; }

    ion-radio {
        --color-checked: #e22078;
    }
}
```

What I want is to color `<ion-label>` to `#e22078` while checking the respective `<ion-radio>`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to bind the value of the selected radio button into a variable. So, declare a variable in your `.ts` file:

```
selectedShippingMethod:string=''; //Or change it to 'flat-rate' for default value
```

Next add a **2-way binding** in your template file so that you can save the value of the selected radio button.

```
<ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedShippingMethod">
  <ion-item class="ship-method">
    <ion-label [class.selected]="selectedShippingMethod=='flat-rate'">Flat Rate £0.00</ion-label>
    <ion-radio slot="end" value="flat-rate"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="ship-method">
    <ion-label [class.selected]="selectedShippingMethod=='free-shipping'">Free Shipping</ion-label>
    <ion-radio slot="end" value="free-shipping"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>
```

Add a class named **selected** in .SCSS file:

```
.selected{

   color:#e22078;
}
```

Here you are assigning ion-label class **'selected'** when the value of `selectedShippingMethod` matches the value of that radio-button

```
<ion-label [class.selected]="selectedShippingMethod=='free-shipping'">
```

Comment: Great. Please mark it as an answer for others to follow. Thanks.